# There is an error in XML document (51888, 30). input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, windows

I have tried to deserialize xml but i am getting "There is an error in XML document (51888, 30). input string was not in correct format."

Below code is uded to deserialize the xml, DOCUMENT is the class which is created from xml

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DOCUMENT));
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(savvisXml);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
    var savvisXMLObj = (DOCUMENT)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    return savvisXMLObj;
    }
```

I am getting error in this line in XML

```
<UNIT_PRICE>0.9800</UNIT_PRICE>
```

UNIT_PRICE is declared as decimal in DOCUMENT class.

Could anyone help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it's not the first or even only decimal in the xml? So the others work? Is there any difference? Maybe it's a culture problem, is the `.` really the correct separator? On my German machine, "0.9800" gets parsed as 9800, because `.` is interpreted as thousand separator, and "0,9800" gets parsed as 0.9800, since `,` is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

Before deserialize try to set the a culture that threat the "." sign as decimal separator:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Maybe a different structure between the class and the xmldata?